# The product of an eigenvector and its transpose in a bipartite graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, proof-explanation, bipartite-graphs

I was reading this proof on the eigenvectors of a bipartite graph[image]

I don't really understand the 3rd line of this proof. How do we know if there even exists such an eigenvector x1 such that $x_1^T*x_1$ =1. Seems like a really arbitrary statement that the entire proof depends on.

Comment: If x is an eigenvector, then so is any multiple of x. They are just saying you should take it to be the unit vector

Comment: @KaragounisZ but how do we know if the unit vector is an eigenvector for this particular matrix?

Comment: Look, they are saying that $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ right? So it has a corresponding eigenvector $v$ so that $Av = \lambda_1 v$. But note that if I take some multiple of $v$, say $2v$ for example, it is still an eigenvector for $\lambda_1$. So there is actually an entire line of eigenvectors for that one eigenvalue. That's why I can choose the specific eigenvector with length 1, i.e the unit vector

Comment: Oh I see, $x^T*x$ is just the dot product of x with itself which is the square of its magnitude. Thank you.